# Vectorize a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I'm using a very large data set with about 3 million observations, and I want to go through and essentially combine certain observations if they meet specific requirements.  I've written a for loop to do this, below, but it is very inefficient.  Is there a more efficient way, say with an apply function or something else, that could improve this?

```
nobs <- nrow(acsdata)

for (i in 2:nobs){

  if (acsdata[i,6]==1 & acsdata[(i-1),6]==1) acsdata[(i-1),3]=2  

  if (acsdata[i,6]==1 & acsdata[(i-1),6]==1) acsdata[(i-1),21:30]=acsdata[(i-1),21:30]+acsdata[i,21:30]

  if (acsdata[i,6]==1 & acsdata[(i-1),6]==1) acsdata[(i),31]=1

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: your data is begging for column names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just vectorize.  Don't mess with a loop or an apply function at all.  Something like (untested):

```
to.fix <- which(acsdata[ 2:nobs, 6] == 1 & acsdata[ 1:(nobs - 1), 6] == 1)
acsdata[to.fix, 3] <- 2
acsdata[to.fix, 21:30] <- acsdata[to.fix, 21:30] + acsdata[to.fix + 1, 21:30]
acsdata[to.fix + 1, 31] <- 1
```

Comment: +1, but `fix` is a function name so perhaps name the index 'to.fix'?

Comment: Thank you very much!  This does exactly what I wanted and very efficiently.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @DWin: `fix` is now fixed, thanks for catching that. Though as I'm sure you know, although it's good practice not to conflict, it actually doesn't cause a problem as functions are looked up in different way than other objects.

Comment: Yes. It's primarily a problem with the wetware.